# Click event on table row - only trigger if nothing else is 'clicked'

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm having some issues with some jQuery code, and I'm hoping and thinking that the solution is relatively simple.

Say I have a table like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="hai" value="der" /></td>
     <td><a href="mypage.php">My link</a></td>
     <td>Some data</td>
     <td>Some more data</td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

Now through JavaScript I do the following in jQuery(document).ready();

```
jQuery("table tr").click(function(){
   var row = jQuery(this);
   var hasClass = row.hasClass("highlight");
   jQuery("table tr").removeClass("highlight");
   if(!hasClass){
     row.addClass("highlight");
   }
});
```

All of this is pretty simple stuff - I want to be able to click a row and have it being highlighted and only one row can be highlighted at a time (obviously in my actual code I do more than that) - now here's my problem:

When a user clicks the anchor tag, or the checkboxes, this triggers the row click event as well and I cannot work out how to filter that out? I know I need to include the event in my click handler, but how to check for this in a such way that it works in as many browsers as possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding handlers to the other elements that respond to click events and stop the event from bubbling up.   This would be in addition to what you already have.

```
jQuery('table input, table a').click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;
}):
```

Comment: can you please explain what this actually means?

Comment: @darkapple events bubble up through the DOM to handlers on higher level elements.  By stopping propagation, we tell the browser not to pass the event up to those elements and thus their handlers will never be invoked.  Returning true allows the default action for the element to continue (e.g., the link to be taken to a new page).  So in this case, we don't invoke the handler that does the row highlight doesn't get invoked if the link or the checkbox is clicked, but is if something else in the row is.

Comment: thanks for the clearification. I was wonderind what was the use of return true.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("table tr").click(function(event){
   if (event.currentTarget.tagName != "TR") { return; }

   $(this).closest("table").find("tr.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
   $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr").click(function(e){

if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement || e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement){
return;
}
var row=$(this);
$('table tr').removeClass('highlight');
row.addClass('highlight','normal');

})
```