# using jquery addclass to add css to table

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to highlight a row in my table when someone clicks on it. Here is my table:

```
<table class="pretty">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Name</td>
        <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Time</td>
        <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Size</td>
        <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Length<td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $this->result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; ?>" title="Mark this video for deletion" /></td>
    </tr>
...
```

I've tried some things based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877351/click-event-on-table-row-only-trigger-if-nothing-else-is-clicked):

```
jQuery("table tr").click(function(){
       var row = jQuery(this);
       var hasClass = row.hasClass("highlight");
       jQuery("table tr").removeClass("highlight");
       if(!hasClass){
         row.addClass("highlight");
         alert("Do I get here?");
       }
});
```

My css. **EDIT**: Added full css which may be the problem:

```
table.pretty {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
clear: both;
}

/* Header cells */
table.pretty thead th {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808184;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
border-top: 4px solid #2B3D61;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
text-align: center;
}

/* Body cells */
table.pretty tbody th {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808184;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
border-top: 4px solid #2B3D61;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

table.pretty tbody td {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
color: #333333;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center;
}

table.pretty tbody tr {
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Footer cells */  
table.pretty tfoot th {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808184;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
border-top: 4px solid #2B3D61;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
text-align: left;
}

table.pretty tfoot td {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808184;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2B3D61;
border-top: 4px solid #2B3D61;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
text-align: center;
}


.highlight{
background-color: #a8cb17;
}
```

For some reason the row color doesn't change. I tried putting the jquery code (minus the click) in the DoNav function which just starts a video when you click on the row.

What am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? I can see nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Perhaps the table is built dynamically? If so, you need delegation

Comment: Perhaps the table cells have their own background that hides the row background?

Comment: Like @JanDvorak said, maybe .highlight declaration in your css is earlier then table's style declaration.

Comment: @WojciechJasiński why so? The clicks do bubble.

Comment: @Tom Your code works it adds the `.highlight`. What is the issue?

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right I was about to write only `table td` cause I'm not sure if one can attach click event to TR

Comment: @WojciechJasiński I can't see why table rows shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: @JanDvorak I suspect you're right. Must be my css, but I fail to see the issue...I can add a hover on tr elements without a problem, weird how I can't change it.

Comment: @Tom option one: some other selector is more specific; option two: you have an inline style there; option three: The cells have their own colors that override the row color.

Comment: @JanDvorak maybe you can have a look, I've updated the post with the extra css. I think it maybe option 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your CSS

```
table.pretty tbody td {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
   ...
}
```

sets all table cells light grey.

```
.highlight{
   background-color: #a8cb17;
}
```

sets the background of anything highlighted to light green.

*You are highlighting rows, but each cell within the green row is still gray* even though the line itself is green.

To fix this, override the cell color instead. Also beware of specificity issues  :

```
table.pretty tbody .highlight,
table.pretty tbody .highlight > td{
   background-color: #a8cb17;
}
```

Note that `.highlight>td` won't suffice since `.highlight>td` (one class, one tag) is less specific than `table.pretty tbody td` (one class, three elements).

Comment: thanks for looking. I wasn't aware of this but that still didn't work. Do I need to change the jquery to use td instead of tr?

Comment: @Tom specificity issues strike again. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

What you have should work, but is unnecessarily complex. Here's the same piece of code, much shorter:

```
var $rows = jQuery("table tr");
$rows.click(function() {
    $rows.removeClass('highlight');
    jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkxNa/